# /usr/share vs /usr/local/share: Where to install CA certs?

Tags: ssh

I have a VM and I want to install a CA cert on it. In other posts, some recommended copying the cert file into `/usr/share/ca-certificates` and some recommended `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`.

I was wondering how are they different and which one I should use.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the answer is in [man update-ca-certificates](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/update-ca-certificates.8.html)

- /usr/local/share/ca-certificates - all are automatically treated as trusted
- /usr/share/ca-certificates - the ones that should be trusted are selected within the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf

More details in this answer and its comments (and the other answers too):
https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu/437377#437377

Answer (score 0):

This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard should be helpful:

#### /usr/local:

> Tertiary hierarchy for local data, specific to this host. Typically has further subdirectories, e.g., bin, lib, share
>
> Historically and strictly according to the standard, /usr/local is for data that must be stored on the local host (as opposed to /usr, which may be mounted across a network). Most of the time /usr/local is used for installing software/data that are not part of the standard operating system distribution (in such case, /usr would only contain software/data that are part of the standard operating system distribution). It is possible that the FHS standard may in the future be changed to reflect this de facto convention.

#### /usr/share:

> Architecture-independent (shared) data.

So I would use the `/usr/local` option.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you're going to use the certificate, and with which application. Read the documentation for that application, and it *should* tell you where to install your certificate.

Or pick one, test, pick the other, test.